# Random forest survival analysis crashes

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm trying to run a RFSRC on a 6500 records dataframe, with 59 variables:

```
rfsrc_test <- rfsrc(Surv(TIME, DIED) ~ ., data=test, nsplit=10, na.action = "na.impute")
```

It seems to work when I run it on 1500 records, but crashes on the entire dataset.
It crashes R without any specific error - sometimes it gives "exceptional processing error".
Any thoughts how to debug this one? I skimmed the database for weird rows without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know the size of each record, nor the complexity of the variables.

I have encountered similar situations when I have hit the RAM overhead. R is not designed for massive data sets. Parallel processing will resolve this, however R is not designed for this, the next suggestion is to buy more RAM.

My approach would be to reduce the number of variables until you can process 6500 records (to make sure its just the data set size). Then I'd pre-screen the fitness of each variable e.g. GLM and use variables which explain a large amount of the data and minimise the residual. Then I'd rerun the survival analysis on a reduced number of variables.

Comment: thank you. so each record contains 59 variables (11 numerical, and the rest are categoricals), the last 2 are time (numerical) and died (logical).     so i thought about RAM - so i put it on my PC which has double the RAM of the laptop - no help....

Comment: The classic sign of a RAM bottle neck is that the calculation progressively slows down until it crashes or hits a standstill. If it is crashing quickly, this may not be the answer. Simply doubling the RAM may not be sufficient. HOWEVER, if you can process more records, e.g. 2500 instead of 1500 it suggests RAM is the issue

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is the time variable - how many different values exist? The survival forest will save a cumulative hazard function for each node. If the number of unique time points in the dataset is large than the CHFS grow large as well..  had to round my time variable and this significantly reduced the run-time.

Comment: oh wow, i didn't know about that. it's any number between 1 and 3000 days...so almost 2000-3000 different options...should i bin those? doesn't it take the whole sting out of SRC?

Comment: Yes i would consider binning the time variable. It depends on the accuracy you require. Does it matter if you predict 2100 days instead of 2093 days?